# getting warning messages while sending push notification to multiple iphone device

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

While i am sending  push notifications to multiple iphone devices using php webservices i am getting warning messages like :

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL: crypto enabling timeout in /home/sample_app/pushnotification.php on line 66

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in /home/sample_app/pushnotification.php on line 66

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /home/sample_app/pushnotification.php on line 66

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/sample_app/pushnotification.php on line 79
```

This is my code :

```
$message='testing';
$q1="select devicetoken from tbl_devicetokens";
$re1 = mysql_query($q1);
while($row1=mysql_fetch_row($re1))
{
    pushMessage($row1[0],$message,'myapp');
}


function pushMessage($deviceToken,$message,$app) {
    echo "Sending iPhone Push Notifications to " . $deviceToken . "<br /><br />";
    echo "Your Message: " . $message . "<br /><br />";
    $time = time();
    $apnsHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
    $apnsPort = 2195;
    $apnsCert = 'apns-myapp.pem';
    $streamContext = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
    $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
    if($apns) {
            $payload = array();
            $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'badge' => 0, 'sound' => 'default');
            $payload = json_encode($payload);
            $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
            fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
    } else { 
            echo "Connection Failed - iPhone Push Notifications Server";
            echo $errorString."<br />";
            echo $error."<br />";
    }
    //socket_close($apns);
    fclose($apns);
}
```

So, can any one tell me how to solve this problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078182/openssl-file-get-contents-failed-to-enable-crypto

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196145/apn-php-code-giving-warning-stream-socket-client-function-stream-socket-clie

Comment: this is not your full code. Paste your full code.

Answer (score 1):

might seem like a dumb answer, but have you tried your firewall / iptables? Those errors without further information look like connection issues to me. First thing you need to resolve is the timeout problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does this still happen when you push a single notification to a single device?

If it does:

- Are you sure that you have the correct path to the certs?
- Make sure that the cert file name does not contain other than alphabetic characters.

If not:

- Make sure that you are using the correct cert for the correct device environment (development, production)
- If a device is jailbroken it will not receive push notifications.

Comment: Yes,Warning messages are getting while i am sending push notifications to single device , even after giving correct path to the certs and not allowing alphabetic characters in the cert file name