# Getting Warnings in the php push notification script

Tags: php, push-notification

I am writing php code to send push notifications to multiple iphone devices..
While i am executing php code i am getting warning message 
in the below line

```
$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
```

like

```
Warning: pack() [function.pack]: Type H: illegal hex digit in /myapp.com/pushgrams/pushtest.php on line 39
```

Can any one tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: `$deviceToken = $payload = ?` So that we can reproduce the error ?

Comment: payload is `$payload = array();
   $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'badge' => 0, 'sound' => 'default');
   $payload = json_encode($payload);`

Comment: `$deviceToken` is more important ?

Comment: yes, $devicetoken is important and the devicetoken which i am giving is `a9e3a660924c2bf96b6540fe78697bed9fe85332e44323cbe4dbd6b04120eaaf`

Comment: I [can't reproduce](http://codepad.org/As3PQFyZ) your error. Are you sure that $deviceToken doesn't have tabs or something like that ? Try to use `preg_replace('#[\t\r\n\s]#', '', $deviceToken)` instead of `str_replace`. Also try to use `var_dump` which should give you the length of the variable.

Comment: k.. it is working, but error new errors like 
`Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL: crypto enabling timeout in /myapp.com/pushgrams/pushtest.php on line 118

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in /myapp.com/pushgrams/pushtest.php on line 118

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /myapp.com/pushgrams/pushtest.php on line 118
Connection Failed - iPhone Push Notifications Server
0`

Comment: so `preg_replace()` did the job ?

Comment: yes. but i am getting the above warnings, how to solve this

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a personal helpdesk for debugging purposes. If this solved your problem and you have another one that is basically not related to it. You should do some research. When you get stuck, ask a *new* question.

Comment: k. I have done lot of research about the above warnings, but i dint get any solution, So, i am asking you..

Comment: @lalith458 Try using `tls://` instead of `ssl://` - although the above comment is correct in that this is a completely separate problem and should be addressed with a new question. Keep in mind that the main aim of StackOverflow is to generate quality content that others can easily find to help them solve similar problems - so if you have a distinct issue you should create a distinct question, showing what you have tried to solve *that* specific problems, so others can see the logical path that one would follow to resolve such a problem.

Comment: @lalith458 I can't believe you since it's technically impossible to do `lot of research about the above warnings` in 10 minutes.

Comment: I am researching about to solve the above issues since 2 days, but i dint any answer,  so, i am asking you

Comment: i have already posted a new question about above issues in the below post "http://stackoverflow.com/q/17205925/1774312", but i dint get any suitable answers

Answer (score 0):

This is how you pack for Apple Push Notification:

```
// APNs packet prepare
function pck($token, $notification, $msg_id = 0, $expiration = 604800) {
  $token = str_replace(" ", "", $token);
  $pck  = pack('CNNnH*', 1, $msg_id, $expiration > 0 ? time() + $expiration : 0, strlen($token) / 2, $token) . 
          pack('n', strlen($notification)) . $notification;

  return $pck;
}
```

This is how you prepare the notification:

```
$m = '{"aps":{"alert":"' . $msg. '","sound":"default"},"acme2":["bang","whiz"],"acme3":["bing","bong"]}';
$p  = pck($k, $m);
```