# Alternative method to find if APNS certification file is valid?

Tags: python, ios, validation, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm having problem developing a ["provider" in APNS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9). My server is trying to send messages using [apns-client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apns-client/0.1.8), it seems there are no problems occuring while sending messages, but the device isn't receiving any messages at all.

Recently I've changed the *.pem file to a new one. Messages were properly received while using the previous *.pem file, so I'm sure that there are no problems at server connections and sending script (written in Python). The reason is, probably, because the old *.pem file is valid but the new *.pem file is not.

I strongly desire to have an "error" response from the APNS server if the *.pem file is invalid, but it seems that the APNS server or apns-client library isn't returning any error signals even if *.pem file is invalid. I've proved this fact by adding one hundred `'a'`s to the line before before `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` in *.pem, and running the same python script. Yes, it still didn't receive any error messages.

Since APNS server is returning no error messages, it's nearly impossible to check if the *.pem file is valid... Aren't there any methods to check if the *.pem file is valid?

Comment: When I generate my certificate it asks me for some key which was specified when I export it from key chain. When I start application it asks me for key in console, I become sure that my certificate loads correctly, then I simply delete this key. One more thing I notice it is that if you delete your provision profile, it does not print anything

Answer (score 5):

Here's some troubleshooting info suggested by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG43):

> **Problems Connecting to the Push Service**
>
> One possibility is that your server is unable to connect to the push
>   service. This can mean that you don't have the certificate chain
>   needed for TLS/SSL to validate the connection to the service. In
>   addition to the SSL identity (certificate and associated private key)
>   created by Member Center, you should also install the Entrust CA
>   (2048) root certificate on your provider. This allows TLS/SSL to
>   verify the full APNs server cert chain. If you need to get this root
>   certificate, you can download it from Entrust's site. Also verify that
>   these identities are installed in the correct location for your
>   provider and that your provider has permission to read them.
>
> You can test the TLS/SSL handshake using the OpenSSL s_client command,
>   like this:
>
> $ **openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert
>   YourSSLCertAndPrivateKey.pem -debug -showcerts -CAfile
>   server-ca-cert.pem**
>
> where server-ca-cert.pem is the Entrust CA (2048) root certificate.
>
> Be sure the SSL identity and the hostname are the correct ones for the
>   push environment you're testing. You can configure your App ID in
>   Member Center separately for the sandbox and production environment,
>   and you will be issued a separate identity for each environment.
>
> Using the sandbox SSL identity to try to connect to the production
>   environment will return an error like this:
>
> CRITICAL | 14:48:40.304061 | Exception creating ssl connection to
>   Apple: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:480: error:14094414:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate revoked

Comment: Entrust CA (2048) already exists but in the certificate chain i can see a message "The issuer of this certificate could not be found." instead of "This certificate is OK."

Answer (score 3):

To test you **PRODUCTION** cert, open Terminal and do this:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert PushProdCer.pem -key PushProdKey.pem
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with the python-client you are using but surely there is a way to simply attempt opening a connection with Apple's PNS servers and detecting whether that connection failed or not. If the connection fails, then something is wrong with the PEM file - either the format or the certificate values themselves.

If you want to get an error message that's a little more explicative than "pass or fail," I recommend you look into 3rd party shell scripts that can return some basic information about the PEM file. This [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/618370/check-expiry-date-of-ssl-certificate-for-multiple-remote-servers) contains a few sample scripts.

Of course, you can also check for some basic format validations that are widely available. I provided one such example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196145/apn-php-code-giving-warning-stream-socket-client-function-stream-socket-clie/15203324#15203324) but there are others.