# IOS APN for Push Notification in PHP

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications, apn

When i send push notification from xampp, notification has been sent. But after upload the files in server, it will show the error as:

> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection refused).

How can i solve the issue?

Comment: Probably problems with certificates.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196145/apn-php-code-giving-warning-stream-socket-client-function-stream-socket-clie][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196145/apn-php-code-giving-warning-stream-socket-client-function-stream-socket-clie